How to configure Fishbowl Inventory with Self-Signed JKS certificate
I'm trying to configure Fishbowl Server Advanced with a JKS Certificate and it seems to not be working as expected.
The software documentation here only informed to use the certificate, but won't give any further instruction on how to create the self-signed certificate.
To create the self-signed certificate I used the keystone.exe that is installed with the application on C:\Program Files\Fishbowl\jre\bin with command below.
keytool -genkeypair -alias fishbowl -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keystore fishbowl.jks -validity 365

Read documentation and made a couple of tests with different places informing how to create a self-signed JKS certificate.

I was able to establish a secure connection to Fishbowl server using a self-signed certificate by performing the following steps:

Create a keystore .jks file using keytool or equivalent 3rd party application (i.e. keystore explorer)
Configure Fishbowl Server to use the keystore.jks file using the Fishbowl Administrator application. Be sure to restart Fishbowl Server afterwards.
Export the certificate and public key from the keystore .jks file using keytool or equivalent 3rd party application (i.e. keystore explorer)
Import the certificate to the cacerts file for the Fishbowl Client located at C:\Program Files\Fishbowl\jre\lib\security\cacerts using keytool or equivalent 3rd party application (i.e. keystore explorer)
Ensure the network/firewall port is open for the port selected (i.e. 2456) between the Fishbowl Client and Fishbowl Server
Launch Fishbowl Client, enter the Server Address, uncheck "Use Legacy Connection", check "Secure Connection", and enter the Server Port that was originally selected within Fishbowl Administrator


what commands did you explicitly run for steps 1, 3 and 4?  I receive an error saying the cert and key are identical when I try to import the cert

I used the Keystore Explorer app rather than the Java Keytool method. I created a new .jks file and then generated a keypair within the file using Keytool Explorer. After the key pair was created, I exported the certificate and public key using Keystore Explorer. I used the .jks file I created (which contains the keypair) to configure Fishbowl Server. I used the exported certificate to import into cacerts for the Fishbowl Client.
